# Update grouped records in Oracle with an incremental value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

So a dilemna, I have an Oracle table called T_GROUP. The records in the table have a unique id (ID) and they are part of a Study, identified by STUDY_ID, so multiple groups can be in the same Study.

```
CREATE TABLE T_GROUP
(
    "ID" NUMBER(10,0),
    "GROUP_NAME" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
    "STUDY_ID" NUMBER(10,0)
)
```

The existing table has hundreds of records and I now add a new column called GROUP_INDEX:

```
ALTER TABLE T_GROUP ADD (
 GROUP_INDEX NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT(0)
);
```

After adding the column I need to run a script to update the GROUP_INDEX field as such: it should start at 1 and increment by 1 for each group **within a study**, starting with the lowest ID.

So now I have data as follows:

```
ID  GROUP_NAME      STUDY_ID    GROUP_INDEX
-------------------------------------------
1   Group 1         3           0
2   Group 2         3           0
3   My Group        5           0
4   Big Group       5           0
5   Group X         5           0
6   Group Z         6           0
7   Best Group      6           0
```

After the update the group_index field should be as follows:

```
ID  GROUP_NAME      STUDY_ID    GROUP_INDEX
-------------------------------------------
1   Group 1         3           1
2   Group 2         3           2
3   My Group        5           1
4   Big Group       5           2
5   Group X         5           3
6   Group Z         6           1
7   Best Group      6           2
```

The update will be run from sqlplus via a batch file. I've played around with group by and sub queries but I'm not having much luck, and having never used sqlplus I'm not sure if I can use variables, cursors etc. All tips greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the analytic function `row_number` for this

```
UPDATE t_group t1
   SET group_index = (SELECT rnk
                        FROM (SELECT id,
                                     row_number() over (partition by study_id
                                                            order by id) rnk
                                FROM t_group) t2
                       WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

Comment: That, sir, is most excellent. It works on my little table of 8 records so I'll test it on dev/test dbs tomorrow and if it works you're getting a big green tick!

Comment: This works fine for small tables, but it has O(N^2) performance ... Use merge statement when dealing with larger tables.

Comment: Thanks Rob - any chance you could show an example of how to use merge in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a version using the MERGE statement. Might be faster than the sub-select (but doesn't have to be).

```
merge into t_group
using 
( 
   select id, 
          row_number() over (partition by study_id order by id) rnk
   from t_group
) t on t.id = t_group.id 
when matched then update 
   set group_index = t.rnk;
```

This assumes that id is the primary key (or at least unique)

I can't test it right now, so there might be some syntax error in it.